# Xamarin.Forms It doesn't add pins to my database

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this json `{"Id":20,"X":11212.0,"Y":212121.0,"RouteId":10,"Route":null}`

What am I doing wrong?

```
private async void OnButton(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            Pin pin = new Pin
            {

                Label = "Nazwa",
                Address = "adres",
                Type = PinType.SavedPin,
                Position = new Position(Convert.ToDouble(szerokosc.Text), Convert.ToDouble(dlugosc.Text))

            };
            piny.Add(new Position(Convert.ToDouble(szerokosc.Text), Convert.ToDouble(dlugosc.Text)));
            Polyline polyline = new Polyline
            {
                StrokeColor = Color.Blue,
                StrokeWidth = 6
            };
            foreach (Position pos in piny)
            {
                polyline.Geopath.Add(pos);

            }
            maps.Pins.Add(pin);
            maps.MapElements.Add(polyline);

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { X = pin.Position.Latitude, Y = pin.Position.Longitude });

            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            var result = await client.PostAsync("URL", content);

            if (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Komunikat", "Dodanie puntku przebiegło pomyślnie", "Anuluj");
            }           
        }
```

Comment: there is no database code here.  If the database code is on your server, you should post the relevant code.  The json you are passing to your server is just X & Y, it does not contain the other elements shown in the first line of your post.  Please read [ask] and [mcve] for help on posting better questions.

Comment: He wants to add co-ordinates for now to API. Sorry for my weak language

Comment: Have you tested the API with a tool like Postman?  Are you sure the problem is not in the API code?

Comment: in postman, everything normally sends

Comment: what is the status code returned by the server?

Comment: status 201 created

Comment: when it fails it returns a 201?

Comment: maybe I have something wrong with my code? (visual)

Comment: when you're successful 201

Comment: what is the return code on failure?

Comment: 400 bad request

Comment: that seems like useful information that you should have included in your post.  If you can get it to work in Postman, then I'd suggest you compare your Postman request to what you're doing in C# and see what is different.

Comment: this code var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { X = pin.Position.Latitude, Y = pin.Position.Longitude }); is good for this json {"Id":20,"X":11212.0,"Y":212121.0,"RouteId":10,"Route":null} ?

Comment: no, those are obviously different.  Since you have not posted your server code I have no idea what it expects.  My first guess would be that you are not including all of the required properties so it is throwing a 400.  You should also check all the header values to be sure they match.

Comment: what should JsonConvert.SerializeObject look like? for this json? I don't have access to API because someone else makes api

Comment: you are missing ID, RouteId, Route - have you tested in Postman with those values missing?